# GCC profile guided optimization with shared library with no control over executable

Tags: optimization, gcc, profiling

We tried gcc's profiling options on an Audio Unit that we compiled under gcc4.2/MacOS. (Technically it is a library.) The problem is that we don't have control over the executable that is loading the library. Ergo we can only link the library with the profiling option but not the executable.

How (if at all) can we use profile guided optimization under these circumstances?

Cheers!

Comment: I believe you're out of luck.  You might be able to have an initialization routine in your library turn on profiling - in which case, you would not get profiling for the code before the library is loaded.  But since the executable is not prepared for profiling, the chances are it won't produce very useful information.  It might produce useful information about your library code, but I wouldn't want to rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you write a custom executable to load (and test) the library? That would be under your control and could be built with profiling.

Comment: Yes, but the API that we needed to call is somewhat complicated. We might go this route at some point but first I need to convice somebody that unit tests are a good thing ;-)